# How do asynchronous calls avoid collisions when updating the same state store variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, asynchronous, operating-system

I have a variable called `sum=0` then I have a loop that executes asynchronous function 2000 times, each one will return a value.
I need to sum all the values returned from the 2000 calls into my variable sum.

How can I guarantee that 2 of the 2000 calls won't access the variable sum at the same time and miscalculate the sum ?

For example :

```
Current sum : 50
Call X fetches value of : 8
Call Y fetches value of : 10
```

The 2 calls try to add the values they got to the value sum through `sum = sum + returnedValue`, in that operation they fetch the current value of `sum` (for both will be 50) and each of them tries to add their own `returnedValue` at the same time.

So now call X will try to set the value of `sum` to **58** and call Y will try to set it to **60** (and only one of them will succeed), while the actual value should be **68**.

How does this case get handled ?

Comment: JS is single-threaded (unless you use workers, but you don't), so only one piece of code can execute at any time, even in asynchronous cases. Therefore you don't have to worry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're guaranteed that `sum` will only be updated by a single thread (never two simultaneously) because JavaScript guarantees that only one single thread can access the [realm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) (loosely: the global environment and the stuff within it) in which your variable exists (directly, or indirectly in a function's environment within that global environment).

For Node.js in particular you can find the details [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/). For browsers, [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops).

For a long time, the JavaScript spec was silent on this and so in theory it was down to implementations, but popular implementations (those in browsers and in Node.js) used a single thread when running the JavaScript code within a realm, and doing that dramatically simplifies some kinds of things (such as your concurrent access situation), so the common near-universal practice was [codified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-agents) in the specification. (Which proved a very useful precursor to the subsequent addition of [shared memory](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-memory-model) — memory shared between realms and thus, potentially, between threads.)

Comment: If you'd like to learn more about shared memory and how it works across threads, I cover it in depth in Chapter 16 of my new book -- links in my profile if you're interested. But you don't need to read that to be secure that your `sum` won't get updated simultaneously by two threads. :-)